# Typical IE issues when trying to align videos - please advise

Tags: javascript, html, css, orientation

Can somebody please tell me why these three items, (video+image+video) align themselves perfectly in every browser accept IE?

In IE they stack on top of each other.

Thank you all in advance.

```
<div style="float: left;"><iframe width="100" height="50" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lhNg7A88no8?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<div style="float: left;"><img style="display: block; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" title="Example dataset from SmartScan" src="http://smartfibres.com/pictures/Example_Data_Set.jpg" alt="Example dataset from Smartscan" width="200" height="100" />
<style="text-align: right;"></div>
<div style="padding-top: 10px, float: left;"><iframe width="100" height="50" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2louwAc63pM?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: I.E is no good. Add HTML tag to your quetion

Comment: I'm trying Steve. I'm that new to this that I cannot get the code up on screen!

Comment: Show us your code so that we can help you. If you can't put it in here, then consider putting it into a jsfiddle.

Also, many questions come out of your question; how are you aligning them? what css properties do they have? etc etc

Comment: I have managed to update the code! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Why are your styles inline? Do you not have an external stylesheet? You should only use inline styles for HTML Emails...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `float` property, but you haven't cleared the floats. This could be what is potentially causing these issues. I've updated your code in the following fiddle and have also taken out your inline styles and put them in a stylesheet of sorts:

http://jsfiddle.net/efrSh/1/

Is there no other CSS? In cases like this, often if the 3 divs width + their padding is larger than the containing div, this will happen. But since you have no other code, I can only assume that your float are not cleared.

Further reading can be found [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that in IE10 the objects are still stacking up on top of one another rather than standing side by side like they do in Chrome/Firefox etc

Comment: Hmmm. Strange problem. Are you using a container for the 3 divs? Have you cleared the floats?